# How to prevent swayidle from execution while watching a film

Tags: linux, configuration, wayland, arch

I am trying to setup [Sway](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Sway) with [swaylock](https://github.com/swaywm/swaylock). My configuration in my `~/.config/sway/config` is as follows:

```
exec swayidle -w \
    timeout 1800 'swaylock -f -c 000000' \
    timeout 3600 'swaymsg "output * dpms off"' \
        resume 'swaymsg "output * dpms off"' \
    before-sleep 'playerctl pause' \
    before-sleep 'swaylock -f -c 000000'
```

However, this also locks my screen after 30 minutes of watching a movie in the browser (I use Chromium for this). Is there a way to disable swayidle while watching a movie? I couldn't find any hints in the [man pages](https://man.archlinux.org/man/swayidle.1).

I run Sway on Arch Linux.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, for all following questions I will (and already did) refer to one of those platforms. However, deciding which one to use is still a hustle for me.

Comment: @Barmar don't be that guy. This most certainly IS a programming question. What do you think a sway config is?

Comment: @RichieHH I don't know what Sway is. And the definition of "programming" can be fuzzy. But I generally fall on the side of considering programming to involve some notion of variables and/or control flow. Configuration is usually just a list of settings, with little in the way of programming.

Answer (score 4):

Try it:

```
for_window [class=".*"] inhibit_idle fullscreen
for_window [app_id=".*"] inhibit_idle fullscreen
```

If you have some window in fullscreen mode, this make stop swayidle

Comment: Where do you put this? Is this sway config only? I'm using hyprland and trying to achieve same thing.

Comment: @Pleklo yes, this ist sway config only. i don't know exactly how make it in hyprland. Maybe: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Hyprland#Idle

Answer (score 0):

<s>I'm using `systemd-inhibit sleep infinity` right now, which seems to be working as intended.</s>

Comment: Nope, this doesn't work, we'd need to disable the `swayidle` process first and renable it afterwards. Since I startup my `swayidle` process inside `~/.config/sway/config` right now, I'm not quite sure the best way to do this yet.